# Install Enterprise Apps in iphone from another app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am trying to develop an application which lists a set of enterprise application along with the installation status,whether it is installed in device or not.If any of the app is not installed in the device then I need to install that app by clicking a button.We have a custome appstore also for these enterprise applications.In this website when the user clicks "Install" button then the app automatically starts downloading and installing on the device.My concern is that,is it possible to do this installation from my app by just clicking a button?.In the web page the action for the button looks similar to the below one :

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://example.com/     manifest.plist">Install App</a>
```

I need to know whether this action can be replicated from an iphone app

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

You can use 
[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:] to open that URL